# Mongoose .pre('save') giving a error. Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I try the hash password `.pre` hook isn't allowed to save it.

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  let user = this as UserDocument;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(config.get("saltWorkFactor"));

  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  user.password = hash;
  return next;
});
```

Is returning an error like

> "Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.ts"

I added generic to pre method. But still the same.

Comment: Typescript allows to compile with this style, I don't know why it shows an error but it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe typo for the last `return` statement, it should be `return next()`.

Besides, you don't need to use a TS type cast for `this` anymore from *mongoose 6.x*

TypeScript knows that `this` is a `mongoose.Document & User` by default. see [generic-parameters](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/6.x/docs/typescript/schemas.html#generic-parameters)

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

interface User {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<User>({
  email: String,
  password: String
})

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  let user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
  return next();
})
```